# "Could not authenticate you" during friendships/create using twit npm package

Tags: node.js, twitter

I have a NodeJS applications that interfaces with Twitter through the [twit](https://github.com/ttezel/twit) library. I'm using both the streaming and the REST api in my application. Streaming works nice, some to the REST calls too, but for some reason,

```
twit.post('friendships/create', {
      screen_name: tweet.user.screen_name,
      follow: false
    }, function (err, resp) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log('friendship gave error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
      }
      console.log('friended');
    });
```

always returns an error:

```
friendship gave error: {"message":"Could not authenticate you","statusCode":401,"code":32,"allErrors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}],"twitterReply":"{\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Could not authenticate you\",\"code\":32}]}"}
```

I'm pretty sure I am authenticated properly, otherwise the other calls to twitter would'nt work... Any thoughts?

Thanks!
nick.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue:
twit library doesn't properly deal with booleans as arguments for calls:
I changed

```
follow: false
``

to

`follow: 'false'`

and the problem was solved.

Nick.